# Is there a cross-browser css way to decorate only last word in a span block?

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout

I need to show user's list which should look like in the example below:

> Helen **Burns** 
>  Edward
>   Fairfax **Rochester** 
> Bertha
>   Antoinetta **Mason** 
> Adèle
>   **Varens**

Is there a way to achieve this without using javascript? Each row should be one span, i.e. `<span>Helen</span><span>Burns</span>` is not acceptable.

Comment: What about JS that changing the HTML structure (wrapping last words with <span>) at runtime?

Comment: Would <span>Helen <span>Burns</span></span> be acceptable? Otherwise there's no :last-word CSS selector.

Comment: You need to be more specific, I think. This could easily be done by doing <span>Helen <strong>Burns</strong></span>, but something tells me you may be trying to do something else.

Comment: What if someone has two last names? you can't select only the last word, there has to be some sort of semantics.

Answer (score 8):

No, there is not.  You are going to have to use some form of scripting to accomplish this if you don't want your last names to be in their own tags.

To the browser, each row is an element, and the "words" themselves have no separate meaning as far as CSS is concerned.  You must place the words in different tags in order to do what you want.

Answer (score 3):

The browser does not automagically know what part of the name is the last name so you have to add extra markup to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

There's no solution for common used browser for know using only CSS. You should use javascript or HTML + CSS as you already made.

Answer (score 1):

without pure css this is impossible (as you don't want a separation in the markup)...

```
<span>Monty Burns</span><br />
<span>Bart Simpson</span>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var spans = $('span');
    spans.each(function(index, element) {
        var span = $(element);
        var spanText = span.text();
        var spanTextArray = spanText.split(' ');
        var spanTextArrayLength = spanTextArray.length;
        var lastName = spanTextArray[spanTextArrayLength -1];
        spanTextArray.pop();
        var firstName = spanTextArray.join(' ');
        span.text(firstName);
        var spanLastName = $('<span/>');
        spanLastName.css('font-weight', 'bold');
        spanLastName.css('margin-left', '5px');
        spanLastName.appendTo(span);
        spanLastName.text(lastName);
    });
});
</script>
```

[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UVHxZ/).

**edit:** if you do not want an extra `span`-tag in there, just change

```
var spanLastName = $('<span/>');
spanLastName.css('font-weight', 'bold');
```

to

```
var spanLastName = $('<strong/>');
```

Comment: You should include your code snippet inline, instead of referencing http://jsfiddle.net/ -- it will make it easier for other to search for your code here.  Not that JsFiddle isn't useful (it is), but your answer is small enough that it makes sense to include it here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible with CSS because your example doesn't show any order:

Helen **Burns**
   Edward Fairfax **Rochester**
   Bertha Antoinetta **Mason**
   Adèle **Varens**

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you might desire not to have an extra tag surrounding the last name (as other answers and comments have suggested), but if you are looking simply for minimalist mark-up, this works (no `span` even used):

Html:

```
 <body>
    First Middle <strong>Last</strong>
    First Middle <strong>Last</strong>
    First Middle <strong>Last</strong>
 </body>
```

Css:

```
strong:after {content:' '; display: block;}
```

Which creates "rows" with your desired styling without anything more than a single tag (which could be a `span` rather than a `strong` if you desired).

Edit: Of course, this will not work for IE7 or under.